# How to Ajax replaceWith(Django form's {% csrf_token %})

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, replacewith

I'm trying to replace a 'reply' button with a form in my Django app.

[image]

Here's my Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.comment-reply-link', function(e) {
$(this).replaceWith("<form method='post'>{% csrf_token %}<div class='form-group'><label for='comment'>Comment:</label><textarea class='form-control' id='comment' rows='5' maxlength='300' minlength='1' name='comment' placeholder='Tell us how you loved this product :D'></textarea></div><button type='submit' name='post_comment' value='True'>Comment</button></form>");});
// The replacing line should contain no whitespace.
// Otherwise it will raise Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I get the form element but the problem is that {% csrf_token %} is processed as just unicode in replaceWith(). {% csrf_token %} is necessary in Django to submit a form. Any kind of help and advice will be thankful :)

[image]

**Edit:**
I assume that {% %} means that Django needs to be involved to retrieve the right value. So I thought I should render an html page with form and update that form with 'reply' button. Here's my logic.

view.html

```
<div class="reply">
<a class='comment-reply-link' href='{% url "rango:reply_form" %}'aria-label='Reply to Araujo'>Reply</a>
</div>
```

reply.js

```
function ajax_get_update(item){
$.get(url, function(results){
//get the parts of the result you want to update. Just select the needed parts of the response
// var reply_form = $("#reply_form", results);
var reply_form = $(".head", results);
console.log(reply_form);
//console.log(results);

//update the ajax_table_result with the return value
$(item).html(reply_form);
}, "html");
}

$(document).on('click', '.reply', function(e) {
console.log("Debuggin...");
e.preventDefault();
url = ($( '.comment-reply-link' )[0].href);
console.log(url);
ajax_get_update(this);
});
```

reply_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
... code omitted ....
<form id="reply_form" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="comment">Reply:</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="5" maxlength="300" minlength="1" name="comment" placeholder="Tell us how you loved this product :D"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="post_comment" value="True">Reply</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the reply button, the button disappears but nothing updates. The html page variable results gets the correct html page data but it seems like

```
$(item).html(reply_form);
```

is not working right. Because when I do

```
$(item).html('<p>button disappears</p>');
```

the paragraph will appear. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax ?

Comment: I added that Javascript getCookie() from the documentation into my javascript and the decorators(csrf_protect and ensure_csrf_cookie)to my view function but it didn't work.... Did I use it wrong?

Comment: Well, instead of using ajax to render a form, why not just have your form under the "reply" button, with style display: none;, then when "reply" is clicked, show the form and use jquery `hide` to hide the reply button?

Answer (score 0):

To use django template language in javascript you should encapsulate your code in a [Verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) tag.

**example :**

```
{% verbatim %}  
    var hello = {% if some_condition %} 'World' {% else %} 'foobar' {% endif %};
{% endverbatim %}
```

**From the docs :**
Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block tag.
A common use is to allow a JavaScript template layer that collides with Django’s syntax

**In your case :**

```
<script>
    {% verbatim  %}
        $(document).on('click', '.comment-reply-link', function(e) {
            $(this).replaceWith("<form method='post'>  {% csrf_token %}  </form>")
        };
    {% endverbatim %}
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like it should work but the javascript couldn't listen to clicks anymore :(